# Vue v-model in two-way binding components communication using TinyMCE Rich Editor

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Following Vue docs: https://vuejs.org/guide/components/v-model.html and https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/integrations/vue/#forminputbindingsv-model
i tried to implement it in my code:
TinyMCE editor- custom input:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <p>This will be Editor JS</p>
    <div name="editor">
      <Editor
        :value="modelValue"
         @change="$emit('update:modelValue', $event.target.value)"
        api-key="key"
        :init="{
          plugins: 'lists link image table code help wordcount'
        }"
      />
      <button>show text</button>
      <p>results</p>
      <div v-html="text"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
// FIXME HIDE THE API KEY

import Editor from '@tinymce/tinymce-vue'
import { defineProps, defineEmits } from 'vue'
defineProps(['modelValue'])
defineEmits(['update:modelValue'])
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped></style>
```

and the parent component:

```
  <template>
  <div class="h-sceen flex w-screen flex-col items-center justify-center gap-5">
    <div>hello from test</div>
    <div class="h-[300px] w-[300px]">
      <TinyMCE v-model:text="text" @update:modelValue="handleTextUpdate"></TinyMCE>
      <div
        v-html="text"
        name="result"
        class="flex h-[300px] w-[300px] items-center justify-center border-2 border-black"
      ></div>
      <button @click="console.log(text.value)">See the text</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import TinyMCE from './TinyMCE.vue'
import { ref } from 'vue'
const text = ref('')
const handleTextUpdate = (newValue) => {
  text.value = newValue
}
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped></style>
```

but in the parent component, I still cant access or see the text from child component. What i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`v-model:text="text"` is incorrect.  The `:text` part is only needed if the prop in the child component is something *other than* `modelValue`.  Since it is, the v-model simplifies to just `v-model="text"`.

Following that, `v-model` as [explained in the documentation](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/v-model.html) is shorthand for

```js
:model-value="text"
@update:model-value="newValue => text = newValue"
```

Meaning you don't need both `v-model` AND `@update:modelValue` (or its method).  The `@update:modelValue` and the functionality of your `handleTextUpdate` method is already provided for you.

This is all the component in your parent needs to be:

```html
<TinyMCE v-model="text"></TinyMCE>
```

Finally, from what I can tell from the docs, tinymce editor does not act like a typical HTML `<input>` element.  The event I believe you want to listen to is called [selectionChange](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/integrations/vue/#forminputbindingsv-model) calling a handler function with arguments for both the event and editor reference. The text with HTML tags needing to be retrieved comes from the editor reference and the `getContent()` method on that reference.

```html
<Editor
  :value="modelValue"
  api-key="key"
  :init="{
    plugins: 'lists link image table code help wordcount'
  }"
  @selection-change="emitContent"
/>
```

```js
<script setup>
import Editor from '@tinymce/tinymce-vue'
import { defineProps, defineEmits } from 'vue'

defineProps(['modelValue'])
const emit = defineEmits(['update:modelValue'])

function emitContent(event, editor) {
  emit('update:modelValue', editor.getContent())
}
</script>
```

Comment: its works! thanks! i was working on this for days but now it works! real G top G!